# Find with Regex, and specific Path

Tags: find, regular-expression

Trying to find a list of files from a set variable. However the path needs to be specific.

```
filename=part-of-filename
```

Does not work:

```
find $HOME -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex "$filename-[[:digit:]]{4}-connect\.xml"
```

Also does not work:

```
find $HOME -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex "$filename-[[:digit:]]{4}-connect\.xml"
```

Works, but finds too much. Why is it forcing me to use '.*/'? $HOME is completely ignored here.

```
find $HOME -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex ".*/$filename-[[:digit:]]{4}-connect\.xml"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it forcing me to use '`.*/`'?

From **`find`** documentation:

> **-regex *pattern***
>                 File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match **on the whole path**, not  a  search.   For  example,  to
>                 match a file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression `.*bar.` or `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. I also realized I can modify the maxdepth and set the start location to narrow down the results.


IE:
`find ${HOME} -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/${filename}-[[:digit:]]{4}-connect\.xml"`